# How can I trim spaces in font of my data?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trim my data in `column O` in `Column N`, it works when I use `function =Trim(O2)`, but I need to use Excel `VBA` code to do this.

After I run my code below it show same thing as `Column O` in `Column N` the data that I want to trim.

can help Anyone this my problem.

Below are my code and data

```
Sub TRY()
    Columns("N:N").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Dim row1 As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        row1 = .Range("N2").End(xlDown).Row

        For i = 2 To row1
            .Cells(i, "N").Value = Trim(.Cells(i, "O").Value)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: My data]

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.Trim`. It's not the same as `Trim`, which is `VBA.Trim`.

Comment: I don't get it. You are dealing with numbers, what do you want to trim?

Comment: I want to trim out the space, because the space will cause error while I import data into Access

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
.Cells(i, "N").Value = Trim(.Cells(i, "O").Value)
```

with:

```
.Cells(i, "N").Value = LTrim(.Cells(i, "O").Value)
```

This will remove only **leading spaces** in a string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help but I have try this it doesn't work.